# How to implement OnClickListener interface in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

How to implement OnClickListener interface in Kotlin as we do in Java, and handle the ids like switch case? For example, I have two buttons and on click of each button, I have to call a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the onclickListener interface like this and override its onClick method and you can use **WHEN** statement as shown! as there is no switch statement in kotlin
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**1: How to implements OnClickLister**

```
button.setOnClickListner{
//call your funtion
}
```

**2: Switch case**

We have `when` in kotlin instead of a `switch`. It's just like `switch` with superpowers.

To know more about `when` go to this link.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html